# ¿Qué se almacena en un servidor web y qué se almacena en la base de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos, servidor, almacenamiento

Tengo poco en ese lubro y a la hora de entrar a la base de datos y los servidores webs siempre me ha quedado poco clara qué es lo que se debe de almacenar puramente en el servidor web como suele ser por ejemplo; un servidor web creado con Node.Js y una base de datos de MongoDb.
Me pasa sobre todo, porque veo que en este tipo de base de datos no es muy útil para guardar archivos de otro tipo que no sea texto. Entonces la pregunta final seria ¿Qué se almacena en una base de datos y qué en el servidor web?
Dispensen mi ignorancia y les agradezco su atención por adelantado.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Lamentablemente tu pregunta se basa en opiniones, motivo por el cual podría terminar cerrada. Sin embargo, si te vas a la definición exacta de cada concepto te encuentras con que el servidor de base de datos y el servidor web tienen básicamente el mismo propósito: atender solicitudes o peticiones y servir contenido o recursos. Cada uno maneja un protocolo diferente. Y en cuanto a lo que almacenas, pues en uno será datos, en otro lógica para acceder a recursos. Para archivos, se usa un servidor de archivos.

Comment: Entiendo que te confunda el hecho de que puedas almacenar datos binarios en una base de datos y ficheros con datos de texto en el servidor web, las fronteras son difusas... :)